# error occured while Access was communicating with OLE server or ActiveX control

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a problem with Access 2010, my database been created with Access 2008 and it worked good, now i try to run database with Access 2010 and when on one form is combo box i try to choose anything on it appear table with error:

> The expression after update you entered as the event property setting produced the following error:A problem occured while Access was communicating with OLE server or ActiveX Control.
>
> - The expression may not result in the name of macro, the name of a user-defined function, or [Event Procedure].
> - There may have been and error evaluating the function, event or macro.

I cant understan on Access 2008 everything was working perfect....

Comment: There is no MS Access version named 2008.  Are you thinking of MS Access 2007?

Comment: Omg you are right, i cant believe i was so stupid and mixed everything, it was created with Access 2013, and now i try to open with 2010, i really need make it work, maybe there is any option to convert it to earlier version?

Comment: That's quite possible, but you'd need to check on the 2013 instance if so.

Comment: Hmm i'd installed Access 2013, but still the same promblem with OLE server...